# Numpy - how do I erase elements of an array if it is found in an other array

Tags: numpy

TLDR: I have 2 arrays `indices = numpy.arange(9)` and another that contains some of the numbers in indices (maybe none at all, maybe it'll contain `[2,4,7]`). The output I'd like for this example is `[0,1,3,5,6,8]`. What method can be used to achieve this?

Edit: I found a method which works somewhat: casting both arrays to a set then taking the difference of the two does give the correct result, but as a set, even if I pass this result to a numpy.array(). I'll update this if I find a solution for that.

Edit2: Casting the result of the subtraction to a list, then casting passing that to a numpy.array() resolved my issue.
I guess I posted this question a little prematurely, given that I found the solution for it myself, but maybe this'll be useful to somebody in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of boolean masking:-

```
indices[~numpy.isin(indices,[2,4,7])]
```

**Explanation:-**

we are using `numpy.isin()` method to find out the values exists or not in incides `array` and then using `~` so that this gives opposite result and finally we are passing this boolean mask to indices